# How to write routine to escape double quotes in a JSON string

Tags: bash, shell, json

I have to be efficient so I can't use tools like `jq` which loads up a big binary executable. I just want to escape double quotes in a string so it's safe for JSON. This isn't good enough:

```
echo ' bad \"  string"' | sed 's/"/\\"/g'
```

because it will escape double quotes that are already escaped. Is there a way to replace double quotes only if they are not already escaped?

Comment: What environment is that you are in that considers a simpler executable `jq` to be bad? I would suggest using `jq` anyway for its myriad of functionalies

Comment: I only need one piece of functionality and it's for another library so I don't need to load a big executable

Comment: It doesn't make sense if you don't wanna use `jq` and use another third party tool instead

Comment: How about the other characters that would also need to be encoded for json (like control characters)?

Comment: How is `sed` any better than `jq`? On my system, `sed` is more than 5 times the size of `jq`. When you include the size of the libraries their are linked to, `jq` is slightly bigger, but that's mostly down to libm which will already be in memory anyway. `jq` takes 60% more time to start than GNU sed on my system though.

Comment: Is your application restricted by the speed at which external utilities can be launched?

Comment: Or maybe it's an embedded system? Details would help steer the choice of answers.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you only want to escape `"` unless it preceded by `\`.

```
echo ' bad \"  string"' | sed -E 's/([^\]|^)"/\1\\"/g'
```

#### Explanation

This will match `"`, but only if it's preceded by `[^\]`, which is "any character except `\`" (or the start of the line `^`). However, since this new character will be replaced itself, we need to capture it in a capturing group `()`, then replace it again with the match `\1`. In this example, I've used extended regular expressions with `-E` for simplicity.

Comment: upvoted, but yeah unfortunately it won't work in cases like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471705/what-rule-determines-escaping-in-json, I need to add more logic to it

Comment: I need to escape unescaped escapes or whatever lol

Comment: @AlexanderMills Could you please edit your question with a sample input and output, including what should and should not be altered?

Comment: There's probably a few edge cases, basically need to produce a string that can surrounded by double quotes and not have any double quotes in it that aren't escaped, but if something is already escaped cannot double escape it.

Comment: @AlexanderMills The "however JSON works" is what confuses me. If you could give explicit examples in your question, that would help us answer you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo ' bad \"  string"' | perl -pe 's/(?<!\\)"/\\\"/g'
 bad \"  string\"
$ echo ' bad \"  string" """""""""' | perl -pe 's/(?<!\\)"/\\\"/g'
 bad \"  string\" \"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"
$ echo ' bad \"  string" """"""""" \"' | perl -pe 's/(?<!\\)"/\\\"/g'
 bad \"  string\" \"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\" \"
```

using negative lookbehind, you can achieve this. https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html